# Cross-origin error with X-Frame-Options:sameorigin?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, iframe, iis-7

My HTML page with an `iframe` displays an `asp.net` webform on button click. Both pages (the html and webform) are hosted in our intranet; they're the same IP but different ports.

I kept on getting `SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin...` so I ended up adding `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` to both `IIS` folders. I can see both in *Chrome developer tools*, but I continue getting the error.

I understand the CORS error, but the `iframe` is within the HTML. So why is it that the iframe changes to a *different domain* once the iframe is loaded? I only receive the error once the webform is loaded.

And is there a solution? Thanks.

[image]

Anyways, here's the HTML:

```
<html class="no-js" lang="">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="storeTable" style="width: 900px; height: 200px;"> 
    <iframe id="retailframe" src="" width="900px" height="800px" scrolling="no" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" ></iframe> 
</div>
    <input type="button" value="Capacity Chart" onclick="CapacityChart();">
    <script>
function CapacityChart()
{
    var doc = document.getElementById('retailframe').contentWindow.document;
    doc.open();
    doc.write('Test');
    doc.close();
    var storeSite = "http://10.12.34.83:88/Grid.aspx";
    var store = document.getElementById('retailframe');
    store.src = storeSite;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> So why is it that the iframe changes to a different domain once the iframe is loaded?

It doesn't.

The error message says the **origins** are different.

An origin is the combination of URL scheme + hostname + port.

Different port == different origin.